# Search a pattern with awk in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file of 3GB. As of now i am opening the file and trying to grep a pattern in before 20 mins from the current time .But it is taking too much of time to grep the pattern.Is there any way so that i can make it fast.Below is the format of my file :

```
08:25:26 <Some text>
08:25:26 <Some text>
08:25:26 <Some text>
08:25:26 <Some text>
08:25:27 TxnEngine
08:25:27 <Some text>
08:25:27 <Some text>
```

As of now i am using below :

```
grep TxnEngine <FileName>  2>/dev/null
```

Please help me how we can use awk to make this fast.

Comment: Why do you think awk will be quicker?

Comment: not sure about you question  need to put some check against time so i thought from awk $1 will have the time there i can check the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `grep` and `awk` process line by line. So you may not see much difference in performance of the two.

However since you are sure that the `TxnEngine` is the second word in a line, you can write a better search using `awk` as

```
$ awk '$2 == "TxnEngine"' filename
```

Here we compare only the second word to `TxnEngine` and we do a string match instead of a regex match, which should supposedly make it faster.

---

`Awk` gives you flexibility to compare the different fields selectively instead of searching the entire line.

Comment: thanks but i need to check the time also it should get only text that are printed in last 20 mins from the current time

Comment: @Developer You can compare the dates using the first column as `$1 > date`

Comment: how we can specify range that it should grep only in last 20 mins text

Comment: @Developer Something like, `awk -v date="$(date -v-20M +"%H:%M:%S")" '$2 == "TxnEngine" && date < $1'`

Comment: this command is not working  awk -v date="$(date -v-20M +"%H:%M:%S")" '$2 == "TxnEngine" && date < $1' filename
date: invalid option -- 'v'
Try `date --help' for more information.

Comment: awk -v date="$(--date="-20 minutes" +"%H:%M:%S")" '$2 == "TxnEngine" && date < $1' filename
-bash: --date=-20 minutes: command not found

Comment: @Developer It should be `awk -v date="$(date --date="-20 minutes" +"%H:%M:%S")" '$2 == "TxnEngine" && date < $1'`